# Speed up creation of list of objects from python dict

Tags: python

I have a dict with keys (edit: 13 keys) that correspond to an object property and lists with values. I now want to create a list of objects for every value in those arrays.

Here is a simplified example:

```
import time

class Person:
  def __init__(self, ID, name):
    self.ID = ID
    self.name = name
    
N = 100000
test_dict = {"name": ["dummy"]*N, "ID": [i for i in range(N)]}

start = time.time()
persons = []
for data in zip(*test_dict.values()):
    single_dict = {key: value for key, value in zip(test_dict, data)}
    persons.append(Person(**single_dict))
print(f"elapsed time {time.time() - start:.4f}")
```

This relatively simple example takes 0.12 seconds. I'm currently creating a new dict for every object but I can't seem to find a way that avoids this (the order of the keys in the dict is not the same as the order in the object).

Comment: If you want to avoid creating a new dictionary for each object, you can modify your code slightly by directly passing the values from the `test_dict` arrays to the `Person`

Comment: Is *numpy* significant in this question? Can you rewrite your code to avoid numpy and still demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just change the loop to this?

```
for i in range(len(test_dict["name"])):
    persons.append(Person(**{key: test_dict[key][i] for key in test_dict}))
```

Or, try this:

Get the order of the parameters for `Persons.__init__`:

```
import inspect
class Person...
parms = str(inspect.signature(Person.__init__)).strip(')').split(', ')[1:]
```

Then write your loop like this:

```
for i in range(len(test_dict["name"])):
    persons.append(Person(*[test_dict[parm][i] for parm in parms]))
```

Comment: Yes, this could work. The only problem is that my actual problem has 13 attributes, so I would be typing quite a bit...

Comment: I edited the suggested loop. Take advantage of the fact that your lists are in sync.

Comment: You may want to precompute `arrays = [test_dict[parm] for parm in parms]` before the main loop, to save a dict lookup in the inner list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

So first as a simple baseline just creating N persons takes time on its own.

```py
from profilehooks import profile


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, ID):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name

N = 100000


@profile()
def person_inits():
    return [Person('dummy', i) for i in range(N)]

person_inits()
```

This takes 0.052s on my machine. Your version takes 0.169s. So keep in mind that the `person_inits` function is like the lowest amount of time it can take, if you want to create 10000 objects. If this is still too slow you have to think about the overall design.

So I will just assume the worst case for you. You do not know the order of dict keys before and you want to init classes with varying number of parameters, with any order and any name. What you can do is reorder the dict and then do what the other comments already pointed out.

```py
import inspect
from dataclasses import dataclass

import numpy as np
from profilehooks import profile


@dataclass()
class Person:
    def __init__(self, ID, age, name):
        self.ID = ID
        self.name = name
        self.age = age


N = 100000


def remap(key_source, keys_target):
    return [keys_target.index(k) for k in key_source]


@profile()
def correct_order():
    test_dict = {"ID": np.arange(N), "age": np.random.randint(0, 100, size=N), "name": np.array(["dummy"] * N)}
    persons = [Person(*values) for values in zip(*test_dict.values())]
    return persons


@profile()
def reorder_version():
    test_dict = {"age": np.random.randint(0, 100, size=N), "name": np.array(["dummy"] * N), "ID": np.arange(N)}
    dict_keys = list(test_dict.keys())
    init_keys = list(inspect.signature(Person.__init__).parameters.keys())[1:]  # [1:] to skip self parameter
    mapping = remap(dict_keys, init_keys)
    test_dict = {dict_keys[i]: test_dict[dict_keys[i]] for i in mapping}
    persons = [Person(*values) for values in zip(*test_dict.values())]
    return persons


@profile()
def inital_version():
    test_dict = {"age": np.random.randint(0, 100, size=N), "name": np.array(["dummy"] * N), "ID": np.arange(N)}
    persons = []
    for data in zip(*test_dict.values()):
        single_dict = {key: value for key, value in zip(test_dict, data)}
        persons.append(Person(**single_dict))
    return persons


persons_inital = inital_version()
persons_correct_order = correct_order()
persons_reorder = reorder_version()

for p1, p2, p3 in zip(persons_inital, persons_reorder, persons_correct_order):
    if p1 != p2 or p2 != p3:
        raise RuntimeError('Not equal')
print('All equal')
```

I used inspect to get the order of parameters for the given class. The dataclass is just to have any automatic generated `==` function for the class to be able to easily compare it to test if my version is the same as yours. I used the [profilehooks](https://pypi.org/project/profilehooks/) package to measure the execution time. I also added age to see if it works for more than 2 parameters.

This seems to work and it takes around 0.1s for me to run.

I do not like the use of `inspect` like this but it is probably the best way to do it for the case where you have almost no knowledge about your data structures and input. This version can handle changes in parameter order and count like your initial version.

All in all it would still be best to have the dict ordered the same way as your parameters or at least have a fixed order so you can compute the mapping beforehand. So you do not need to use `inspect`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating many instances of a class, you can use `__slots__` to reduce the overhead.

```
class Person:
  __slots__ = ['ID', 'name']
  def __init__(self, ID, name):
    self.ID = ID
    self.name = name
```

Then switching up the list comprehensions a bit:

```
persons = [Person(**dict(zip(test_dict, data))) for data in zip(*test_dict.values())]
```

The result is 25% faster with your example.

Edit: I was reminded about them by the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76686348/2403000) by Nopileos, a dataclass is faster than using slots. After doing this it's 35% faster.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass()
class Person:
    ID: str
    name: str
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid creating a new dict for each object try the following:

```
persons = [Person(*values) for values in zip(*test_dict.values())]
```

Console output:

```
elapsed time 0.0920
```

Comment: Because the order of the keys in `test_dict` and the `Person` class is not the same, this unfortunately doesn't work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If Byron's answer works for you, then here is a faster version.

Instead of this:

```
for i in range(len(test_dict["name"])):
    persons.append(Person(*[test_dict[parm][i] for parm in parms]))
```

, do this:

```
def work(test_dict, parms):
    arrays = [test_dict[parm] for parm in parms]
    len_arrays = len(arrays)
    _range = range
    _Person = Person
    return [
        _Person(*[arrays[j][i] for j in _range(len_arrays)])
        for i in _range(len(test_dict["name"]))]

persons = work(test_dict, parms)
```

Optimizations:

- It does an array indexing (`arrays[j]`) instead of a dict lookup (`test_dict[parm]`) in the inner list comprehensions.
- It uses local variables (faster) rather than global variables within the loop.
- It uses a list comprehension instead of `for` + `.append`.

Also you may want to combine ideas from multiple answers.